# Multidimensional Input to Keras LSTM - (for Classification)

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to classify a bunch of spectrograms into C classes using keras' LSTM (with a Dense Layer at the end). To clarify, each spectrogram belongs to a single class from those C classes. Each spectrogram is basically a matrix. It is constructed by taking (lets say, K) measurements at every second for about 1000 seconds. So the matrix has K rows and 1000 columns.

Considering this, how may I specify the shape of this input for the LSTM layer ?

Thank you!

Comment: ignore the `input_shape` parameter set `input_dim=1000`. The number of rows is irrelevant as far as typing out the model goes. Side question, isn't a spectrogram usually an image? Ref: https://keras.io/#getting-started-30-seconds-to-keras

Comment: Why not use just a fully connected dense network first? 1000 timesteps could be knocking on the doors of the vanishing gradient. Also, we need to see a sample of the code, hard to make suggestions when we cant see what your doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be in the [current documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) for LSTM layers, but `input_shape` can be provided as `(timesteps, input_dim)`.

If each spectrogram to be classified has 1000 time steps and `K` measurements at each time step, an LSTM layer can be constructed like this:

```
LSTM(num_units, input_shape=(1000, K))
```

Then the shape of the input array for all of the spectrograms should have the shape `(num_spectrograms, 1000, K)`.